How to handle timeslots in vugen scripting?
I am working on the application where timeslot is involved and it is dynamic.
In a week- 5 days will be having slots ranging from 9 AM to 6 PM but not always same slots available for all days.
And only one user is allowed to use one slot.
While selecting slots, in request I can see days and slots are selected in number.
Example- Monday will be 2 nd day and 9 AM will be considered as 1.
So in request,it will pass as days(2).slots(1).
I tried Parameterization to control this but once slot is selected, it is disappearing on next iteration which is obvious and slot count changes so it's failing on few final iterations.
In correlation, as slot is depending on day, when user is selecting, atleast one user will fail as it chooses same slot.
How to assign 2 correlated values(one is dependent on other) to each user as unique?

You can pregenerate the unique slots available and then place these in a queue, such as the virtual table server, where the data is use once then destroyed or you have multigenerational correlation.(1) correlate for available days, then when the day is selected, correlate for the available time slots.   Then pick the slot.
I would be more likely to go the correlation route so I woudn't have to manage another set of parameters.
